# Move Box Plot Chart 5px to the Left Using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, position, boxplot

I have created a dynamic box plot chart and it was positioned at the center of the page. I would like to shift the chart 5px to the left.

This is the output of my chart currently:

### [image]

I want to shift the chart slightly to the left, like 5px to the left. Does anyone has any suggestion on how this can be achieved?

I have tried **Chart1.Style["right"] = 5.ToString() + "px";** but the chart still stay at the same position.

This is my codes to create the chart:

```
                            Chart Chart1 = new Chart();
                            Chart1 .DataSource = dt;

                            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl Chart1_DIV = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
                            Chart1_DIV.ID = "LVL1RISKCHART_DIV";
                            Chart1_DIV.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.TextAlign, "center");
                            Chart1_DIV.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "100%");

                            Chart1.Series.Add(new Series());
                            Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.BoxPlot;

                            List<object> List1 = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList<object>();
                            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                            {
                                Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(row["DESC"], new object[] { row["MIN"], row["MAX"], row["25TH_PERCENTILE"], row["75TH_PERCENTILE"], row["50TH_PERCENTILE"], row["AVG"] });

                            //create chartareas
                            ChartArea ca = new ChartArea();
                            ca.AxisX = new Axis();
                            ca.AxisY = new Axis();
                            Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(ca);

                            //databind
                            Chart1.DataBind();
                            Chart1.Visible = true;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: hi @Pranav Patel, I have updated my post with the code, please take a look, thanks!

Comment: hi @jstreet, could you repost the solution you provided here yesterday? I think the solution you suggested might work for my scenario. Thanks a lot!